# Group by, get max value of each group and update the group, linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

From a table, I group the elements by name and get the max value of its qty column (quantity) of each group, then I update each group with the max value. I do it this way:

```
 var result = from skuTableElements in tableElements
               group skuTableElements by skuTableElements.Material
               into grouped
               select new 
               {
                 Material = grouped.First().Material,
                 Qty = grouped.Max(x => x.Qty)
               };


  foreach (var item in result) {
    var result2 = from elements in tableElements
                  where elements.Material == item.Material
                  select elements;
    foreach (var item2 in result2) {
      item2.Qty = item.Qty;
    }
  }
```

It works fine with few elements, but I'm guessing with a lot of rows this might take too long.
Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: "but I'm guessing with a lot of rows this might take too long" -- 1) Why do you think that? 2) Sounds like premature optimization to me. What are the time constraints for you to enumerate these results? E.g., high frequency stock trading machines need results in milliseconds or less, but someone producing an excel spreadsheet once a day might have multiple hours.

Comment: Actually, I do not have any restrictions, I'l ltake that in mind

Comment: If performance is what you want, use SQL. SQL is always much faster than your ORM. This should be a fairly simple query, which you can save it in a stored procedure. Even for 100,000 > rows of data, SQL should be able to complete it within a few seconds at most.

Comment: Since Linq is translated into SQL, there is no reason it should be (much) slower than SQL for simple queries. It is possible to determine the SQL translation (LINQPad is useful) and also to have SQL Server show query performance analysis.